# What is the maximum value of $|V|$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, extremal-graph-theory

If $G=(V,E)$ is a connected graph with $|E|=17$ and $deg(v)>2$ for all vertices of graph $G$, what is the maximum value for $|V|=v$?

$deg(v)\geq 3$ for all $v\in V$, $\sum_{v\in V} deg(v)=2|E|=2\cdot 17=34$, thus $34\geq 3v$ and from there $v \leq \frac{34}{3} \approx 11.33$, $v\leq 11$. $v_{\text{max}}=11$.

Those were my thoughts, but it wasn't enough, apparently I only gave an upper bound.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You've shown that the graph has at most $11$ vertices, but you haven't addressed the question of whether there actually are any graphs with $11$ vertices that meet the criteria.  The maximum might be $10$ or even less.

Comment: Essentially $11$ is an upper bound only, is there a way to find out through calculations, or would I have to draw some graphs with vertices and edges to try and disprove it?

Comment: We know that there would have to be $10$ vertices of degree $3$ and one of degree $4$.  There's an [algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/havel-hakimi-degree-sequence-theory) for testing whether it's possible for a graph to have this degree sequence.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your reasoning is correct and one can show that there exists a connected graph with $11$ vertices and $17$ edges:

[image]

Note that I constructed this graph by using your arguments actually, since degree sum was $34$ and $v_{max} = 11$, I consider $10$ vertices of degree $3$ and $1$ vertex with degree $4$. Easiest way to construct such a graph is to consider an $11$-cycle first, then first make a vertex with degree $4$ (this also makes two of the vertices degree $3$ so we are left with $8$ vertices of degree $2$), then try to pair vertices so that they all have degree $3$.

Comment: I have no choice but to draw out an actual graph in this case right?

Comment: Yes, if you suspect that a graph satisfying these conditions can be constructed. But I also added some information about how I constructed this graph, since your approach was totally fine at first.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)